# Why doesn't Codeigniter handle all incoming requests

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter, routes, http-status-code-404

When I type a wrong url after the base url in the browser apache's error page shows up instead of codeigniter's "not found" error page.

For example:

```
somesite.com/index.php/some_wrong_page => Codeigniter 404 page(which is fine)

somesite.com/some_wrong_page => I get apache's "not found" page(which is not what i want)
```

I have a .htaccess that points to the default codeigniter's index.php in the root of the site:

```
php_value register_globals 
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_flag display_errors on
php_value error_reporting 1

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

**EDIT**

Here is a very accurate example of my file structure(linux/apache):

```
-- ROOT
----system(codeigniter resides here, which index.php redirects everything to)
----.htaccess(which redirects everything to index.php below)
----index.php
```

**EDIT**

Can anyone PLEASE help me?

Comment: Check the docs [page](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html) and try to change rewrite block accordingly. Maybe `$path` there is sufficient?

Comment: @Tpojka yes i tried that but still same problem.

Comment: Ok, this is the plan: if default code nor custom code work stick with default one. Default code should work for you. There is sometimes (on some maybe shared servers) situation when you need to add question mark in URL to pretend query string. Are you able to check server's PHP and/or Apache errors?